# How can I mitigate humidity causing me to stop short on the approach?

Tags: bowling

This past weekend, I was throwing a couple of games at a new alley and I found that I was consistently stopping short. To clarify, each time I released my ball, my lead foot wouldn't slide instead it would stop at least a few inches short of where I had hoped it would go to allow for a smooth release.

My shoes were clean, however, it was raining outside and I think some of that humidity was out-competing the house's air conditioning. I tried brushing my shoes just to be sure, but it didn't really help. I also tried adjusting my starting position to make the release closer to the line, however, it didn't really change the fact that my foot was sticking was impeding a smooth release.

Is there anything else that can be done when humidity in the building is making the approach feel sticky?

Answer (score 1):

While humidity may or may not have been the cause that's not strictly speaking relevant since the problem is the difference in friction on the approach to what you're used to. I've known this to vary *wildly* between different centres!

And I'm not alone in this - which is why shoe manufacturers offer interchangeable soles to suit (e.g. Linds' VHS system)

What do you do if you don't have such shoes though? Well there's no great options in my experience - something like Brunswick's [Smooth slide](https://brunswickbowling.com/products/accessories/gripping-products/smooth-slide) is probably your best bet or a dusting from a puffball in a pinch.

Comment: Is using something like that permissible? I don't want to create a slip hazard for other bowlers.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I've never known anyone to have a problem with it - you're applying to to your shoes rather than the approach so unless you're applying way, *way* too much it's not going to really leave any behind to impact others